# Vertical side nav bar - Angular 4 and Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have installed bootstrap 3 in my angular 4 project using the npm installer. I have a basic site done up and am trying to get an dynamic sideNav bar that will toggle in and out.

I have seen some examples online however they do not seem to work whether it be a newer version of bootstrap or compatibility issues with angular.

Does anyone have any recommendations for a navigation bar that I could use in this instance?

The HTML in my `app.component.html`:

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<script src="src/Javascript/sidebar.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <a href="#">
                Brand
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Works <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What did you try? Put some code

Comment: Yes, put up code. There may be a package that makes it more Angular "friendly" or you could include it in the index.html file.

Comment: I am currently using the sidebar seen on this site: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation

I will update the question to show my code

Comment: You could bring up a working example on stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First You need to Import bootstrap 3 or Use Bootstrap 3 CDN

Then Instead of using JQuery Use Directive to manipulate Class and Style of Side Bar

I Have Created Stack blitz for same side Bar without using JQuery Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6hrob

Comment: are u using any npm module for it?

Comment: i am not using any npm module for this. only bootstrap

Comment: hmm what is this sidebar.directive.ts you have imported this in your app module file

Comment: that is angular directive which is used toggle bootstrap class when you click the icon

Comment: if you dont mind could you please come to chat room?

Comment: please do not use jquery in your angular components

Comment: I have not used JQuery

Comment: ... and only 300 lines of cut-and-paste custom CSS.  Anything this prolific should be a drop-in component with a few styles and a simple list of menu items and action callbacks.

Answer (score -2):

You are probably missing following JS Libraries in your code, add these in your `index.html` near end of `<body>` tag:

```
    <!-- jQuery CDN -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Custom Scroller CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
```