# javascript code doesn't affect angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have an angular project . 
I used a template to build it and the template had a lot of javascript, specifically it had many classes that used javascript.
In one of my component i have this html code

```
<button class="how-pos3 hov3 trans-04 js-hide-modal1">
   <img src="../../../assets/images/icons/icon-close.png" alt="CLOSE">
</button>
```

this is a part of a modal , in order for it to work I added the javascript files to the assets folder and also added scripts tags for each one of them in the index.html file .

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
/*[ Show modal1 ]*/
    $('.js-show-modal1').on('click',function(e){
        console.log("close");
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.js-modal1').addClass('show-modal1');
    });

    $('.js-hide-modal1').on('click',function(){
        console.log("open");
        $('.js-modal1').removeClass('show-modal1');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

this is one of the javascript files, this code is suppose to affect the modal every time I press the button in the html code, however when I press the button nothing happen. Furthermore I checked in the console if the line `console.log("open");` is being printed and I didn't see any output which may indicate that this function doesn't being executed when I press the button.
do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: you should not use query inside angular. for you case use directive

Comment: why are you using java script or jquery in Angular ???

Comment: if you want to add class dynamically check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296759/vertical-side-nav-bar-angular-4-and-bootstrap-3/51640113#51640113

Comment: How is it suppose to help me?

Comment: add conditional class with [class.js-show-modal1]="isShown == true" in where you are using modal container. 
set (click) ="toggleModal()" in "js-show-modal1" element.
in your_components.ts =>  var isShown = false;  function toggelModal(){ this.isShown = !this.isShown}

Comment: this is a specific solution ,however I have a lot more javascript and I cant do this for all of it.
thanks for the answer but do you know how can I make the javascript code to work

Comment: if you use jquery look at this https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc

Comment: but I dont activate javascript functions from angular ,the javascript just register for events and when they happen the javascript code is activated