# How to change css styles in Angular on Click for animation

Tags: javascript, css, angular

hey everyone I am building a hamburger menu and when I toggle the menu I want to add/remove a certain css property a existing class. Here's my code

> burger.component.html

```
<div class="top-nav--hamburger--container" (click)="handleHamburger()">
      <div  class="hamburger-bar--top"></div>
      <div class="hamburger-bar--bot"></div>
</div>
```

And my css looks like this

```
.hamburger-bar--top
    width: 30px
    height: 5px
    background: red
    border-radius: 100px
    transition: transform 50ms ease-out
    // transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(5px) translateX(5px)

.hamburger-bar--bot
    margin-top: 8px
    width: 30px
    height: 5px
    background: red
    border-radius: 100px
    transition: transform 50ms ease-out
    // transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-5px) translateX(4px)
```

I want to add those transform properties to the existing class on click and remove them if already applied.

> burger.component.ts

showStyle: boolean = false;

```
  constructor() { }

  handleHamburger(){
    this.showStyle = !this.showStyle;
    ...Add the properties to the class
    ...Can not figure this part out
  }
```

So on click I would like to add the transform properties on the class. I am not sure how to do this. Any help or idea would be great. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a quick job for [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296759/vertical-side-nav-bar-angular-4-and-bootstrap-3/51640113#51640113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ngClass` directive to toggle class base of `showStyle` value.

```
<div class="top-nav--hamburger--container" 
    [ngClass]="{'class01':showStyle,'class02':!showStyle}" 
    (click)="handleHamburger()">
      ...
</div>
```

> in case of multiple class `{'class01 class03 class04':showStyle,'class02':!showStyle}`

Also you can build your class list at `handleHamburger` method

```
  private showStyle = false;
  public classList = {};
  public handleHamburger() {
    this.showStyle = !this.showStyle;

    if (this.showStyle) {
      this.classList = {
        'class01 class02': true,
        'class03': true
      }
    } else {
      this.classList = {
        'classs04': true
      }
    }
  }
```

template

```
<div class="top-nav--hamburger--container" 
    [ngClass]="classList"  (click)="handleHamburger()">
      ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add conditional angular styles like this.

```
<div  class="hamburger-bar--top" ng-style="hamburgerTopStyle"></div>

handleHamburger() {
    this.hamburgerTopStyle = {'font-size': '10px', 'color': 'blue'};
}
```